# How large a current is realistic for a mains wire?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, estimation

I recently encountered this elementary physics question:

> A mains wire outside your house is $15m$ above the ground. The power company says the voltage is $10 kV$, and the wire delivers $18 MW$ of power to the neighbourhood. What is the maximum magnetic field you experience from the wire?

The only tricky part of the question is the last part, since $10 kV$ is the rms voltage so the maximum voltage (and corresponding magnetic field) is larger. However there's a part of the question that's dubious to me: given that $P = VI$ and $P = 18 MW, V = 10 kV$, the current in the wire is $1800 A$. That sounds incredibly large. In fact my intuition is that by around $20A$, the wire is liable to melt from the heat. Furthermore, I remember that in these mains wires, the voltage is artificially increased by a transformer to minimize the current & therefore the heat lost (from $H = I^2R$).

I'm confident the current is $1800A$ (since the calculated magnetic field is correct), but I'm wondering if $1800A$ is a realistic number for the current in the mains wire. If it is not realistic, how large a current is realistic?

Comment: While this looks like a homework-type question it could also be interpreted as more suited to [electronics.se] or even [diy.se].  I note it says "wire outside your house", which implies some form of power transmission line and that could be rated for more than $10$ kV depending on the specific details.

Comment: "in these mains wires, the voltage is artificially increased by a transformer to minimize the current & therefore the heat lost" You are right, but, of course, 10 kV is already far above the voltage supplied to a house, and would need step-down transformers if the power is to be used domestically. But is 10 kV a large enough voltage for transmitting 18 MW economically)? My guess is that it *isn't*, unless very thick – and expensive – conductors are used to reduce the resistance per metre length, but we need an answer from someone with inside knowledge of the power distribution industry!

Comment: A typical current density for copper wiring in free air is 4A/mm^2. In your case that's 450mm^2 of area or 48mm wire diameter. That's a large conductor but I have seen much larger. One would usually not deliver 18MW at 10kV for such an application, but the overall engineering parameters are fine.

Comment: @FlatterMann  Agreed: that would waste only about 130 W per metre, which seems like peanuts, but the cost of the copper, and its weight in an overhead line of any length might be prohibitive?

Comment: It's not a matter of waste but a matter of heating. The losses are most likely considerably higher, by the way. At 60Hz the skin depth in copper is 8mm, so some of the metal in the core is already unused. You are correct that one would probably go with a 66kV or even 115kV voltage for such an application and the system would be three phase, so that reduces the current per conductor considerably.

Comment: @PhilipWood I've cross-posted this to EE SE, maybe someone there will know. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/640872/is-1800a-a-realistic-current-for-a-mains-wire

Comment: @FlatterMann maybe you can write an answer there =)

Comment: It's not even a EE problem. Like I said, I have seen conductors with much larger diameters  (closer to 10,000mm^2) in high energy physics labs. At most you can criticize the pretended application in this trivial question.

Comment: @FlatterMann  Many thanks for the point about the skin depth.

Comment: 20A is a normal 120V circuit in your house (sure, 15A is more common).